# Terraria. Two types of ore at one world

Tags: terraria

From wiki I have know that in Terraria might generate classic ores or alternative ones. But after I have generated world I have seen two types of ores there. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each tier of ore can be either the classic or the alternative variant, but the three tiers are independent of each other.

You can have copper in a world with tungsten and platinum, but not copper and tin in the same world.

Answer (score 1):

Though there are ways of getting the alternate or, such as from crates.  This can be useful because especially with the hardmode ores, what one can make with the classic ore has different effects than the alternate (such as with titanium/adamantite armor).